# Cannot replace line after string match in jenkins pipeline using variables

Tags: jenkins, sed, jenkins-pipeline

I need to replace a line in a file. If the line starts with the term "url", I need to replace the value.

file.txt --

```
...
url : http://www.google.com
..
```

I need to change this value to 
url : http://www.facebook.com

I tried the following code but it did not work -

```
FACEBOOK_URL = "http://www.facebook.com"
sh("sed -i \\"s?^url.*\\$?url: ${FACEBOOK_URL}?\\" file.txt")
```

I'm using a Jenkins Pipeline. I need to replace the string using a variable.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question. I needed the same help.

Answer (score 9):

Jenkins 2 Pipeline builds use Groovy and it is very easy to read the file using [readfile](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-readfile-code-read-file-from-workspace) and then we can do the changes

```
def text = readFile "file.txt"
text.replaceAll("url.*", "url: ${FACEBOOK_URL}")
```

The above code will help in replacing the text in the file, if you want to write the content to file, you can use [writeFile](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#writefile-write-file-to-workspace)

Comment: Im using the older jenkinspipeline. It worked for me. Thank you for saving my time

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this for replacing a string in a file in Jenkins 2 Pipeline builds:

```
def text = readFile file: "file.txt"
text = text.replaceAll("%version%", "${VERSION}")
writeFile file: "file.txt", text: text
```